# ¿Como puedo solucionar este error al ejecutar wampserver?

Tags: wamp

**Tengo el siguiente error al ejecutar Wampserver**

[image: ese es el error al ejecutar Wampserver]

**Ya instalé esto**

[image: ya instale esto]

**Ya instalado el Microsoft visual C++ no me aparecen la librerías que debería tener osea la MSVCR110.dll**

[image: ya instalado el Microsoft visual C++ no me aparecen la librerías que debería tener osea la de MSVCR110.dll]

Comment: Puedes aclarar cual es la pregunta porque hablas de c++ y java son lenguajes muy diferentes

Comment: Intenta reinstalando WAMP

Comment: O en todo caso publica la versión de wamp que estas usando y la versión del paquete de visual que instalaste.

Comment: Intenta desinstalar la version de Microsoft Visual c++, descarga la version 2012 e instalala.